# How do you set the cursor style in Vim terminal windows?

Tags: terminal-buffer, cursor

Vim has the `:terminal` command, which opens a window with a terminal session inside. According to the documentation (`:help terminal-cursor-style`),

> By default the cursor in the terminal window uses a not blinking block. The normal xterm escape sequences can be used to change the blinking state and the shape.

I added the following to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Make the cursor always a blinking underscore
let &t_SI .= "\<Esc>[3 q"
let &t_SR .= "\<Esc>[3 q"
let &t_EI .= "\<Esc>[3 q"
```

That sets the cursor style for regular vim windows, but not terminal windows. How can I override the default "not blinking block" cursor in terminal windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `&shell` is set to `/usr/bin/bash`, then append
`printf '\033[3 q'` to `~/.bashrc`; launch a new `vim`
instance and run `:term` and launch another `vim` instance
from that terminal window and run `:term`, *ad libitum*.

Depending on how the outermost `vim` instance is launched,
you may not need *for it* your three capability lines from
`.vimrc`.